# How do I make my Folder value as a Variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm having this problem:

How am I able to make a folder which is variable?

All I know is `set folder=1` something like that.

```
set folder=-1
set counter=0
:countfiles
set filecnt=0
for %%a in (*) do set /a filecnt+=1
:divideto6
set /a whole=filecnt/6
SET /a "Fraction = filecnt %% 6"
set /a ans=whole+fraction
REM echo ANS: %whole%.%fraction%
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a folder with a batch file? `md %folder%`

Comment: @Squashman Yes, but this so far what I did is  `set folder=-1
set counter=0

:countfiles
set filecnt=0
for %%a in (*) do set /a filecnt+=1

:divideto6
set /a whole=filecnt/6
SET /a "Fraction = filecnt %% 6"
set /a ans=whole+fraction
REM echo ANS: %whole%.%fraction%` I want my set folder as variable ..

Comment: I don't see how that code is relevant. Also, do what Squashman said and set the `%folder%` variable to whatever name you want to give the folder, then use the command `md %folder%` to create the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it in as a command line argument.

When you call a batch file, you can enter data after the command that the batch file refers to as %1, %2, etc. For example, in the batch file hello.bat, the following command

```
@echo hello %1 boy
```

would output

> hello john boy

So you could set your folder name as,

```
@echo off
set FOLDER=%1
ECHO %FOLDER%
if not exist %FOLDER% mkdir %FOLDER%
```

**Edit**

As per your comments below,

You can get the user to enter the number of flowers they need

```
set /p NUMBER=Enter The Number of Folders to Create:%=%
@echo %NUMBER%
```

Then use this number to do a for loop and ask for each folder name and then create them

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
    set /p FOLDER=Enter The Folder Name:%=%
    --create the folder--
)
```

**Edit 2**

Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time. When delayed expansion is in effect variables can be referenced using !variable_name! (in addition to the normal %variable_name% )

EG:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _var=first
Set _var=second& Echo %_var% !_var!
```

You might expect that to produce the output second second but in fact it will output: first second

I don't see it being a problem here, but give it a test :)

Comment: @achinta I want to ask ..how about after asking the number of folders which will be created can you give me an idea how am I suppose to divide it to the number of logs that I have and it will be distributed equally to the requested number of folders

Comment: and one last thing, ahm.. I put setlocal enabledelayexpansion. does it affect the syntax if I use `!` rather than `%` i'm a little bit confused the difference of the two.